# Uploading CSV file to MySql table by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I am trying to write a code on PHP that will allow me to upload some specific columns from a CSV file to MySql table. I'm very new on PHP. Tried to watch some  of tutorials, but they were not much helpful as they are only showing the examples on very little CSV files such as 2 rows and 2 columns... I am talking about approx 100 cols and hundreds of rows. I only need the information from some specific columns to add my table. Here's my code so far.. It gives  Undefined offset error. I am open to new ideas.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'MyPass', 'database') or die('connection failed');

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
     echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
     {

         $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
         $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
            $sql = "INSERT into turbolister(site,format,currency) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
            mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
         }

         fclose($handle);
         echo "Successfully Imported";

     }
     else
     {
         echo "Invalid File";
     }     


} `
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Import File: <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" name='sel_file' size='20'> <br>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="upload" value='upload'>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please show CSV file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a project I would recommend you another way of doing this.

For me there are some open questions:

- Is it correct, that one line in csv is one line in database?
- Is there a header-line in csv containing the column-names so that the order of the columns can change?

I've overworked your script a little bit - what you need to do is to adjust the behavior to your needs and also change the separation item for header-columns and normal-lines.

```
<?php

// Just for development purpose
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
    // Try to connect to mysql-server with pdo instated of using mysqli
    $dbCon = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', 'MyPass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Catching error && stoping script
    die('<strong>Error:</strong> Connection failed with error "' . $e->getMessage() . '"');
}

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];

    // Show filename of uploaded file
    echo 'Uploaded file: ' . $filename . '<br>';

    // Check file-extension for csv
    // @ToDo: Determinate which mime-type your csv-files generally have and check for mime-type additionally or instated
    if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'csv') {
        // Get file-content
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name']);

        // Split file into lines
        $rows = explode("\n", $fileContent);

        // Check for data
        if (empty($rows) || count($rows) < 2) {
            // Shwo error-messages && stopping script
            die('<strong>Error:</strong> CSV-File does not contain data!');
        }

        // Get columns of header-row
        $header = explode('|', $rows[0]);

        // Set query variables
        $query = 'INSERT INTO test (';
        $values = '(';

        // Build query based on header-columns
        for($a = 0; $a < count($header); ++$a) {
            // Add column
            $query .= $header[$a] . ', ';
            $values .= ':column' . $a . ', ';
        }

        // Finish query
        $query = substr($query, 0, -2) . ') VALUES ' . substr($values, 0, -2) . ')';

        // Loop through rows, starting after header-row
        for ($b = 1; $b < count($rows); ++$b) {
            // Split row
            $row = explode(',', $rows[$b]);

            // Check that row has the same amount of columns like header
            if (count($header) != count($row)) {
                // Show message
                echo '<strong>Warning:</strong> Skipped line #' . $b . ' because of missing columns!';

                // Skip line
                continue;
            }

            // Create statement
            $statement = $dbCon->prepare($query);

            // Loop through columns
            for ($c = 0; $c < count($row); ++$c) {
                // Bind values from column to statement
                $statement->bindValue(':column' . $c, $row[$c]);
            }

            // Execute statement
            $result = $statement->execute();

            // Check for error
            if ($result === false) {
                // Show info
                echo '<strong>Warning:</strong>: DB-Driver returned error on inserting line #' . $b;
            }
        }

        // @ToDo: Get numbers of row before import, check number of rows after import against number of rows in file
        // Show success message
        echo '<span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">Import successfully!</span>';
    } else {
        die('<strong>Error:</strong> The file-extension of uploaded file is wrong! Needs to be ".csv".');
    }
}

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Import File: <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" name='sel_file' size='20'> <br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="upload" value='upload'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is really clever way to do it. Very informative
 and helpful !